# Add Header Parameter in Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to call an API which requires me to pass in an API key.

My Service call using `HttpURLConnection` is working perfectly.

```java
url = new URL("https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?entity_id=3&entity_type=city&q=" + params[0]);
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

urlConnection.setRequestProperty("user-key","9900a9720d31dfd5fdb4352700c");

if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() != 200) {
    Toast.makeText(con, "url connection response not 200 | " + urlConnection.getResponseCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d("jamian", "url connection response not 200 | " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
}
```

However, I'm not sure how this works with `Retrofit` as my call in going into Failure at all times.
Here's the code I'm using for the same service call

```
@GET("search")
Call<String> getRestaurantsBySearch(@Query("entity_id") String entity_id, @Query("entity_type") String entity_type, @Query("q") String query,@Header("Accept") String accept, @Header("user-key") String userkey);
```

and I'm using this to call it

```
Call<String> call = endpoint.getRestaurantsBySearch("3","city","mumbai","application/json","9900a9720d31dfd5fdb4352700c");
```

All these calls are going into the `OnFailure` Method in RetroFit.
If I send it without the HeaderParameters it goes into Success with a 403 because I obviously need to pass the api key somewhere but I cant figure out how.

```
@GET("search")
Call<String> getRestaurantsBySearch(@Query("entity_id") String entity_id, @Query("entity_type") String entity_type, @Query("q") String query);
```

The error I'm getting in OnFailure is

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

Comment: add a [logging interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor) for your retrofit instance, because your call is wrong parameterized

Comment: compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.0'

Comment: I used the above dependency. Any Idea how i go about from there?

Comment: @jamian it is depend on okhttp's version use same version

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After trying a couple of times i figured out the answer.

The error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

was coming due the failure of parsing the json.

In the method call I was passing a String instead of a POJO class.

```
@Headers("user-key: 9900a9720d31dfd5fdb4352700c")
@GET("api/v2.1/search")
Call<String> getRestaurantsBySearch(@Query("entity_id") String entity_id, @Query("entity_type") String entity_type, @Query("q") String query);
```

I should have passed instead of Call<**String**> the type of Call<**Data**>

**Data being the Pojo class**

something like this

```
@Headers("user-key: 9900a9720d31dfd5fdb4352700c")
@GET("api/v2.1/search")
Call<Data> getRestaurantsBySearch(@Query("entity_id") String entity_id, @Query("entity_type") String entity_type, @Query("q") String query);
```

Comment: it depends on what type of converter you use. Gson converter for parsing json. or use scalar converter for string. Since you had not mentioned nay of those i had put a note in my answer. Call<String> is possible

Comment: Using Kotlin, I get the error "An Annotation argument must be a compile time constant"

Answer (score 123):

Try this type header for Retrofit 1.9 and 2.0. For the JSON content type.

```
@Headers({"Accept: application/json"})
@POST("user/classes")
Call<playlist> addToPlaylist(@Body PlaylistParm parm);
```

You can add many more headers, i.e,

```
@Headers({
        "Accept: application/json",
        "User-Agent: Your-App-Name",
        "Cache-Control: max-age=640000"
    })
```

Dynamically *add* to headers:

```
@POST("user/classes")
Call<ResponseModel> addToPlaylist(@Header("Content-Type") String content_type, @Body RequestModel req);
```

Call your method, i.e.,

```
mAPI.addToPlayList("application/json", playListParam);
```

Or

Want to pass every time, then *create* an HttpClient object with the HTTP Interceptor:

```
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        httpClient.networkInterceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public com.squareup.okhttp.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request.Builder requestBuilder = chain.request().newBuilder();
                requestBuilder.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
                return chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build());
            }
        });
```

Then add to a Retrofit object

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).client(httpClient).build();
```

If you are using Kotlin, remove the  `{ }`. Else it will not work.

Comment: how to add value dynamically (e.g. 640000 in  ur example)? at runtime?

Comment: You have to add it in okhttp Client.

Comment: I was making the mistake of using curly braces in Kotlin. Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 54):

You can use the below

```
 @Headers("user-key: 9900a9720d31dfd5fdb4352700c")
 @GET("api/v2.1/search")
 Call<String> getRestaurantsBySearch(@Query("entity_id") String entity_id, @Query("entity_type") String entity_type, @Query("q") String query);
```

and

```
 Call<String> call = endpoint.getRestaurantsBySearch("3","city","cafes");
```

The above is based in the zomato api which is documented at

https://developers.zomato.com/documentation#!/restaurant/search

Thing to note is the end point change **api/v2.1/search** and the Header  `@Headers("user-key: 9900a9720d31dfd5fdb4352700c")`.

Also check your base url  `.baseUrl("https://developers.zomato.com/")`

Also i tried the above with a api key i generated and it works
 and my query was **cafes** as suggested the zomato documentation.

Note : I hope you have the below

```
 .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create()) // for string conversion
 .build();
```

and the below in build.gradle file

```
compile group: 'com.squareup.retrofit2', name: 'converter-scalars', version: '2.2.0'
```

Edit:

You can also pass header with dynamic value as below

```
@GET("api/v2.1/search")
Call<String> getRestaurantsBySearch(@Query("entity_id") String entity_id, @Query("entity_type") String entity_type, @Query("q") String query,@Header("user-key") String userkey);
```

And

```
Call<String> call = endpoint.getRestaurantsBySearch("3","city","cafes","9900a9720d31dfd5fdb4352700c");
```

Answer (score 5):

Let me also comment a little bit (*actually a lot*) about adding headers in *Kotlin* focusing on **Dependency Injection**.

The best approach would be to provide both **OkHttpClient** and **HttpLoggingInterceptor** on the same di method making use of the handy Kotlin Scoping function in this case `also` and `apply`.

We will be needing these `Retrofit (2.9)` and `OkHttpClient` dependencies - this example uses *Kotlin DSL* but should be more or less the same in Groovy. Of-course you will be needing other dependencies like *Hilt* if you are using Dependency Injection.

```
implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:5.0.0-alpha.7")
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:5.0.0-alpha.7")
```

Next stop is to create the *@Provide function* which returns `OkHttpClient`.

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideOkHttpClient():OkHttpClient { ...}
```

Background theory about Interceptors is very vital; to use an interceptor, you need to create a class that implements the `Interceptor interface` and ***override*** the `intercept()` method.

`intercept()` receives an `Interceptor.Chain` object - which represents the current request and allows you to proceed with the request by calling the `proceed()` method, or cancel the request by `throwing an exception`. `intercept()` override function returns a `Response` object which is exactly what `chain.proceed(request)` returns.

```
class MyInterceptor : Interceptor {
    //throw an exception to cancel request
    @Throws(IOException::class)

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {

        val request = chain.request()
                .newBuilder() // returns Request.Builder
                .addHeader("Header_1", "value_1")
                .build()

        //proceed with the request
        return chain.proceed(request)
    }

}
```

Thanks to Kotlin *Anonymous Function Syntax* and *Builder Pattern* we can skip the above theory steps and start to build `OkHttpClient`  which has the `addInterceptor()` function.

```
fun provideOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
    
            //build client
            return OkHttpClient.Builder()
    
                    //create anonymous interceptor in the lambda and override intercept
                    // passing in Interceptor.Chain parameter
                    .addInterceptor { chain ->
                      //return response
                        chain.proceed(
                              //create request
                                chain.request()
                                        .newBuilder()
                                       //add headers to the request builder
                                        .also {
                                            it.addHeader("Header_1", "value_1")
                                            it.addHeader("Header_2", "value_2")
                                        }
                                        .build()
                        )
                    }
                    .also { okHttpClient ->.... }
```

In the above code `addInterceptor()` opens up a lambda where we anonymously override `intercept()` passing in a chain parameter.

We use `chain.proceed(request)` to return a `Response`. It is when constructing the *request* to pass to `chain.proceed()` ***that we modify the actual request to add the headers***.

You can also proceed to build up on the OkHttpClient to add timeouts etc.

```
.also { okHttpClient ->

                    okHttpClient.connectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    okHttpClient.readTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

                    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                        val httpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {

                            level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
                        }

                        okHttpClient.addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
                    }
                }
                .build()
```

This is the final code.

```
@Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {

        //build client
        return OkHttpClient.Builder()

                //create anonymous interceptor in the lambda and override intercept
                // passing in Interceptor.Chain parameter
                .addInterceptor { chain ->

                    //return response
                    chain.proceed(
                            //create request
                            chain.request()
                                    .newBuilder()

                                    //add headers to the request builder
                                    .also {
                                        it.addHeader("Header_1", "value_1")
                                        it.addHeader("Header_2", "value_2")
                                    }.build()

                    )
                }
                //add timeouts, logging
                .also { okHttpClient ->

                    okHttpClient.connectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    okHttpClient.readTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        //log if in debugging phase
                    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                        val httpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {

                            level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
                        }

                        okHttpClient.addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
                    }
                }
                .build()


    }
```

This marks my StackOverflow's longest ever post, I'm sorry guys.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see you are passing the data in a wrong way.
Your method `getRestaurantsBySearch` is accepting the last two parameter as header field i.e `accept` and `user-key`. But while calling the method you are passing headers first. 
Pass the data as you have declared it in method signature of `getRestaurantsBySearch`

Comment: can you just post the code that you tried after changing the parameter positions

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please take a look at the response. It clearly shows that the api key you provided is wrong. At first you get the correct api key. Then call the request it will work
.